# Java program unintentionally requires pressing enter twice

Tags: java

I'm making a simple simulation of a slot machine and after working on it for a while, I've gotten it to work for the most part. The only issue is when I ask the user to enter how much money they would like to bet, the program only proceeds when they press enter twice. I have no idea what's causing this and I feel like it's a really easy fix, so any help possible would be very highly appreciated!

Here's the program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SlotMachineSimulation
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Random randomN = new Random();
      DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$###,###,###,##0.00");
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      String fruit1 = "abcd";
      String fruit2 = "abcd";
      String fruit3 = "abcd";
      int slot1 = 0;
      int slot2 = 0;
      int slot3 = 0;
      double finalMoney = 0;
      double factor = 0;
      String aaa = "y";

      while(aaa.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
      {
         System.out.print("Enter the amount you would like to bet: ");
         int bet = kb.nextInt();
         factor = 0;
         for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
         {
            final int maxRandom = 6;
            int slot = randomN.nextInt(maxRandom);
            int iteration = i;
            if(iteration == 1)
            {
               slot1 = slot;
               switch (slot)
               {
                  case 0:
                     fruit1 = "cherries";
                  break;
                  case 1:
                     fruit1 = "oranges";
                  break;
                  case 2:
                     fruit1 = "plums";
                  break;
                  case 3:
                     fruit1 = "bells";
                  break;
                  case 4:
                     fruit1 = "melons";
                  break;
                  case 5:
                     fruit1 = "bars";
                  break;
               }
            }
            else if(iteration == 2)
            {
               slot2 = slot;
               switch(slot)
               {
                  case 0:
                     fruit2 = "cherries";
                  break;
                  case 1:
                     fruit2 = "oranges";
                  break;
                  case 2:
                     fruit2 = "plums";
                  break;
                  case 3:
                     fruit2 = "bells";
                  break;
                  case 4:
                     fruit2 = "melons";
                  break;
                  case 5:
                     fruit2 = "bars";
                  break;
               }
            }
            else if(iteration == 3)
            {
               slot3 = slot;
               switch(slot)
               {
                  case 0:
                     fruit3 = "cherries";
                  break;
                  case 1:
                     fruit3 = "oranges";
                  break;
                  case 2:
                     fruit3 = "plums";
                  break;
                  case 3:
                     fruit3 = "bells";
                  break;
                  case 4:
                     fruit3 = "melons";
                  break;
                  case 5:
                     fruit3 = "bars";
                  break;
               }
               System.out.println("-" + fruit1 + "--" + fruit2 + "--" + fruit3
                                 + "-");
               if(slot1 == slot2 || slot1 == slot3 || slot2 == slot3)
               {
                  if( slot1 == slot2 && slot1 == slot3)
                  {
                     System.out.println("Great! Three Match!");
                     System.out.println("That triples your bet!");
                     factor = 3;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     System.out.println("Great! Two Match!");
                     System.out.println("That doubles your bet!");
                     factor = 2;
                  }
               }
               else
                  System.out.println("Sorry, none match...");
               double rawWinnings = factor*bet;
               System.out.println("You win " + money.format(rawWinnings));
               if(rawWinnings>0)
                  finalMoney = finalMoney + rawWinnings;
               else
                  finalMoney = finalMoney + bet;
               System.out.print("Would you like to play again(enter y or n): ");  
            }
            aaa = kb.nextLine();
            if(aaa.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            {
               System.out.println("You won a total of " + finalMoney);
               System.exit(0);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The second ENTER is needed because the program executes `aaa = kb.nextLine()` and you have to put in something.  But I'm not sure where you really want the "Would you like to play again" question, the `kb.nextLine()`, and the test for `"n"`.  It could be that all of those are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @ajb, the problem comes from the instruction `aaa = kb.nextLine()`. However, let me go into a little more details so you can understand exactly what happens and why.

When you type an integer in the console and then press `ENTER` : Java saves what you type, including an "end of line" character (a.k.a "CR" or "Carriage Return") that is that character associated with the `ENTER` key.

So, imagine you press the keys "1" + "2" + "ENTER", Java saves what you typed as `12\n` (where `\n` is just a representation of the "Carriage Return") in a buffer.

`kb.nextInt()` only reads `12` from the buffer and leaves the `\n`.

Next, you enter the main `while` loop and iterate **3 times** in the inner `for` loop. You call `kb.nextLine()` on every iteration of that inner `for` loop. On the **first iteration**, you don't display anything, but `kb.nextLine()` **reads the `\n` that was left in the buffer**. On the second iteration, you still don't display anything, but the buffer is now empty, and that results in `aaa.nextLine()` waiting for a new line, that you provide it with by pressing one more time `ENTER`. Here stands the main difference between `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` : `nextInt()` does **not** read the `\n`, but `nextLine()` does. Finally, on the third iteration, everything comes back to normal.

To help you understand, here is a cleaned and simplified version of your code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String aaa = "y";

    while(aaa.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.println("Bet ? : ");
        int bet = kb.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            if (i == 3) 
            {
                System.out.print("Would you like to play again(enter y or n): ");
            }
            System.out.println("I read a line !");
            aaa = kb.nextLine();
            if (aaa.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye !");
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, try this version next version that I modified so it would work, and see the difference :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String aaa = "y";

    while(aaa.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        System.out.println("Bet ? : ");
        int bet = kb.nextInt(); // Read the Integer
        aaa = kb.nextLine(); // Read the "\n"

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {

        }

        System.out.print("Would you like to play again(enter y or n): ");
        aaa = kb.nextLine();
        if (aaa.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye !");
            System.exit(0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great, that fixed it perfectly! You've made sure my head/heart ache did not go to waste. And you helped me understand what the problem was, thank you very very much.